# Failed to send attachments in mail-Yii

Tags: php, yii

Here is my code for attaching docs in mails. I am using YiiMail extension for that.

controller-

```
public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        $message = new YiiMailMessage;
        $message->Body=$_POST['ContactForm']['body'];
        $message->subject = $_POST['ContactForm']['subject'];
        $message->addTo($_POST['ContactForm']['email']);
        $message->from = "from@gmail.com";

        //Adding attachment
        //$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file'); // get the CUploadedFile
       // $uploadedFileName = $uploadedFile->tempName;

        $model->file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
        $uploadedFileName =$model->file->tempName; // will be something like 'myfile.jpg'
        $swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedFileName); // create a Swift Attachment from the temporary file
        $message->attach($swiftAttachment); // now attach the correct type

         Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
    }

    $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

I am able to send mails with attachments, but no attachment is found in mail. It says "no preview is available". Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: have you tried `echoing the $swiftAttachment`.. may be path issue should be there..

Comment: ya its giving me some very big unmeaningful code

Comment: why dont you try putting static path and check what happens..

Comment: I have tried giving static path, it says "name or service not known". I have googled a lot and its the same code that is been given everywhere.

Comment: try this `$uploadedFileName = $uploadedFile->tempName;`.... instead of `$uploadedFileName =$model->file->tempName;`

Comment: Both of them mean the same thing. I have tried the other one and I get the same error

Comment: are you getting right file name in `$uploadedFileName` ??

Comment: also try this `$message->attach(
Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/image.jpg')->setFilename('myfilename.jpg')
);`...

Comment: No I'm getting some temp name for $uploadedFileName as /tmp/phpJotXR

Comment: but you comment in code says `will be something like 'myfile.jpg'`.. and yeah have you tried my above given code?  `giving full path to image`....

Comment: may be the error should be it is not getting the file name.. so your email provider (gmail, ymail etc) is not able to determine which type of file it is.. (doc, image, xls etc) so it is showing no preview...

Comment: I have removed the code in my view to upload file and corresponding code in controller,model. I gave the full path to image but then it is not sending any mail. Its just redirecting for long time

Comment: ok check the `permissions` for your image directory.. put 777... and yeah also prevent big sized attachments...

Comment: yea its 777 only..I have tried all ur suggestions. Is it better to use any other extension now?

Comment: if nothing is working than try using `phpMailer` ... first try using custom php code and than integrate it to yii.. it will be easier and if you get any errors than it will be easier to understand..